# No rule to make target '/usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h (after installing g++-8 on ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

On my ubuntu 20.4 machine, to try building a Makefile based program, I tried 'make' but found it needs g++-8. So I added 'universe' repository following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) and installed g++8 by

```
sudo apt install gcc-8 g++-8
```

Now when I run 'make',  I see this message.

> make: *** No rule to make target
> '/usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h', needed by
> 'obj/main.o'.  Stop

Why is it looking for files for redhat linux?? Do I have to do something?

Comment: I'm confused - the link you provided doesn't seem to have anything to do with adding the universe repository.

Comment: The only reason I can think for it to look for redhat files is that the developers of the software have hardcoded the location in the Makefile. You can check whether `g++` itself is the culprit using `: | gcc-8 -E -v -xc++ -` and looking for the section starting `#include <...> search starts here:`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, I was not at thig problem for days, but the gcc-8 default include paths doesn't show the redhat things..